# How to Set a File's Blob Filename?

Tags: plone

In a Plone's File content type, which property stores the file's original filename?

I'm using plone.jsonapi.routes to upload files to a plone instance. I can set the `id` ant the `title` but I can't set the associated file's filename.

For example, when I upload a file to Plone in the regular way, I can set its `id` and `title`, but additionally to that, the original file name is stored somewhere. You can see it here:[image: image showing file name]

`objects-essay.pdf - PDF document` indicates the name the original file has.

But when I upload it with plone.jsonapi.routes that field is empty. So, I'm trying to figure it out which property stores the name to pass it to the api or to set it by hand.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC, all Archetypes-based content types have a [setFilename method](https://github.com/plone/Products.Archetypes/blob/master/Products/Archetypes/BaseObject.py#L346) that you can use to do this.

On Dexterity-based content types file's content is stored in blobs in the ZODB (instances of [NamedBlobFile](https://github.com/plone/plone.namedfile/blob/master/plone/namedfile/file.py#L359)) and there's a parameter named `filename` that you can use to set it.

You can see an example of the later in [plone.app.contenttypes](https://github.com/plone/plone.app.contenttypes/blob/master/plone/app/contenttypes/tests/test_indexes.py#L157).

Comment: Only a note about the Archetyes `setFilename` method. I've an old memory about a weird issue with it: calling it on a created file will destroy the file mime-type.
It's only a warning: maybe recent version of Archetypes fixed it, but beware this behavior.